# How to configure imagePullPolicy from fabric8-maven-plugin

Tags: fabric8

**Context:**

I'm using **fabric8-maven-plugin** to generate the docker image and deploy it to a Kubernetes cluster.

**Question:**

It's possible to configure the **imagePullPolicy** parameter whose default value is **IfNotPresent**?

Current configuration in **pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.25</version>
            <configuration>
                <images>
                    <image>
                        <name>my-service</name>
                        <alias>service</alias>
                        <build>
                            <from>java:8</from>
                            <tags>
                                <tag>latest</tag>
                                <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                            </tags>
                            <!--
                            The entry point path used is "maven/" since this is the default folder: https://dmp.fabric8.io/#building-images,
                            "launch.sh" is copied to the container based in the assembly.xml descriptor file.
                            -->
                            <entryPoint>
                                <exec>
                                    <arg>maven/launch.sh</arg>
                                </exec>
                            </entryPoint>
                            <assembly>
                                <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                            </assembly>
                        </build>
                    </image>
                </images>
                <generator>
                    <includes>
                        <include>java-exec</include>
                    </includes>
                    <config>
                        <java-exec>
                            <webPort>8080</webPort>
                        </java-exec>
                    </config>
                </generator>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What I got is:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
    image: 394148814603.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dkrecr-nafiux-ncp/kcluster-ncp-myservice
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent <---- I want to personalize this value to Always, for instance.
    name: service
    securityContext:
      privileged: false
```

Why I want to change the value to **Always**? Mainly because I'm doing a lot of tests with the cluster, and I don't want to assign a new version to the docker image for each test that I do, at this point.

I appreciate your support.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the parameter that I was looking for:

1) Add latest to the docker image:

```
            <name>myservice:latest</name>
```

2) Add **pullPolicy** in the enricher configuration.

```
            <enricher>
                <config>
                    <fmp-controller>
                        <pullPolicy>Always</pullPolicy>
                    </fmp-controller>
                </config>
            </enricher>
```

Full example:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.25</version>
            <configuration>
                <images>
                    <image>
                        <alias>service</alias>
                        <name>myservice:latest</name>
                        <build>
                            <from>java:8</from>
                            <tags>
                                <tag>latest</tag>
                                <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                            </tags>
                            <!--
                            The entry point path used is "maven/" since this is the default folder: https://dmp.fabric8.io/#building-images,
                            "launch.sh" is copied to the container based in the assembly.xml descriptor file.
                            -->
                            <entryPoint>
                                <exec>
                                    <arg>maven/launch.sh</arg>
                                </exec>
                            </entryPoint>
                            <assembly>
                                <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                            </assembly>
                        </build>
                    </image>
                </images>
                <generator>
                    <includes>
                        <include>java-exec</include>
                    </includes>
                    <config>
                        <java-exec>
                            <webPort>8080</webPort>
                        </java-exec>
                    </config>
                </generator>
                <enricher>
                    <config>
                        <fmp-controller>
                            <pullPolicy>Always</pullPolicy>
                        </fmp-controller>
                    </config>
                </enricher>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Appreciate your efforts to find it out.
ha ha ..race condition :)

Answer (score 2):

Add following enricher config to pom.xml along with generator, images.

```
            <configuration> 
                <enricher>
                    <config>
                        <fmp-controller>
                            <pullPolicy>Always</pullPolicy>
                        </fmp-controller>
                    </config>
                </enricher>
            </configuration>
```

Though this is not ideal way, but will work for the time being.

Comment: Thanks @Hrishikesh!